# C# Working with a generic list in a method

Tags: c#, generics

I have been teaching myself generics and I wanted to try it out with a list but I struggled upon a problem I cant figure out how to "feed" the generic list to my method. What is the proper way to make a generic method "eat" my list? :)

Heres my code:

```
 class Program<AnyDataType>
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        jdtlist.Add("something");
        jdtlist.Add("something");
        jdtlist.Add("something");
        Console.WriteLine(countlist(jdtlist));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static List<AnyDataType> jdtlist = new List<AnyDataType>();

    public static int countlist(List<AnyDataType> list) // Yes I know this is practically useless but thats not why I am here :)
    {
        int listcount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            listcount++;
        }
        return listcount;
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?  How is it not working?  Your question is not that clear.  Also, don't anthropomorphize code.

Comment: What do you mean by "feed" and "eat"?

Comment: Im trying to make a generic method that returns listcount no matter what variable type the list is, but I cant seem to figure out how to do it correctly. Heres a screenschot of my code in VS hope it helps:   http://puu.sh/hFVLW/62cf4c2a03.png   http://puu.sh/hFVOG/986185a223.jpg

Comment: Your screen shot just shows the code you've already given to us except with some errors underlined.  That's of no use without the text of the actual errors.  Come on, man....help us help you.

Comment: @HolyFish any generic list has a property `Count`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are writing generic method, then it should have generic parameter

```
public static int CountList<T>(List<T> list)
{
    int listcount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)        
        listcount++;

    return listcount;
}
```

Then you can call it with any generic list

```
var list = new List<AnyDataType>();
// ..
Foo.CountList(list);
```

Same goes to classes. If you want to parametrize class with some generic type, you should provide generic argument

```
public class Foo<T>
```

As @DStanley stated, you don't need to parametrize individual methods in that case

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public static int CountList(List<T> list)
    {
        int listcount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)        
            listcount++;

        return listcount;
    } 
}
```

But you need to parametrize class

```
Foo<int>.CountList(list)
```

Suggested reading: [Generics (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Comment: the class is generic, so the generic parameter on the method is implied.

Comment: @DStanley yes, I know. Just wanted to show separately generic method definition and generic class definition

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the static method of the generic class via class-name including the type of the parameter:

so instead of

```
Console.WriteLine(countlist(jdtlist));
```

this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Program<string>.countlist(jdtlist));
```

Another way is to make the method generic, not the class:

```
public static int countlist<AnyDataType>(List<AnyDataType> list) {}
```

Then you can call it in these ways(with explicit type or inferred from parameter):

```
Program1.countlist<string>(jdtlist)
Program1.countlist(jdtlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not passing the list to your method - that part is fine.  Your problem is that you're trying to fill a "generic" list with a "specific" type (namely strings).  Making a class generic means "I am not specifying the data type here - the *consumer* of the class will do that".  So a better use case for your class would be:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyList<string>.Add("something");
        MyList<string>.Add("something");
        MyList<string>.Add("something");
        Console.WriteLine(MyList<string>.countlist(MyList<string>.jdtlist));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
public class MyList<AnyDataType>
{
    public static List<AnyDataType> jdtlist = new List<AnyDataType>();

    public static void Add(AnyDataType item)
    {
        jdtList.Add(item);
    }

    public static int countlist(List<AnyDataType> list) 
    {
        int listcount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            listcount++;
        }
        return listcount;
    }
```

This is the *minimum* needed to get your program to work - there are several improvements that can be made (not using static so much, etc.) but hopefully it helps you understand generics better.

Answer (score 0):

Okay you have:

```
public static int countlist(List<AnyDataType> list)
{
    int listcount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        listcount++;
    }
    return listcount;
}
```

And well, it works fine, but only if you have `List<AnyDataType>` to begin with.

Well, you could do:

```
public static int Countlist<T>(List<T> list)
{
    int listcount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        listcount++;
    }
    return listcount;
}
```

Now the method itself is generic. What's more overloads will happen automatically in that you can call  `CountList(new List<string>())` rather than having to explicitly call `CountList<strong>(new List<string>())`.

But this combines with simple matters of inheritance. Consider that your `CountList` could work just as well with any other `IEnumerable<T>` implementation:

```
public static int Count<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
  int tally = 0;
  foreach(var item in source)
    ++tally;
  return tally;
}
```

So just as generics mean you don't have to restrict yourself to a particular type of list, so normal inheritance and interface implementation means you can work with the most general case applicable.